# while calling retrofit get method NetworkonMainThread Exception

Tags: android

when i am calling retrofit get method i am getting `android.os.networkonMainThread` these exception
can any one help this.
this is the get method

```
@GET("/advice/{id}")
    User GetUser(@Path("id") int userid);
```

and in my class

```
restAdapter = RestAdapterManager.getInstance();
    getuser =  restAdapter.create(GetUser.class);
User user=  getuser .GetUser(30).
```

Comment: This is because you are performing your background network operation on main thread. So avoid this exception just use `AsyncTask` or `Thread`.

Comment: actually retrofit will run on background thread. it will takecare of that. post is working with out writing any thread. in get method i am getting this exception.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation, if your method has a return type, it is done synchronously (ie. on the main thread).
To run the request asynchronously, make it return `void` and add a  parameter of type `retrofit.Callback` to your method, as follow:

```
void GetUser(@Path("id") int userid, retrofit.Callback<User> user);
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you need your network operation in a background thread, for this, you can use an AsyncTask

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User>  {
 @Override
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      restAdapter = RestAdapterManager.getInstance();
     getuser =  restAdapter.create(GetUser.class);
     User user=  getuser .GetUser(30). 
      return user;
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
   //DO your UI tasks here
 }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are doing network operation on **mainUI** thread. To avoid this, you have to do network operation on AsyncTask or worker Thread (Background).

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            restAdapter = RestAdapterManager.getInstance();
            getuser =  restAdapter.create(GetUser.class);
            User user=  getuser .GetUser(30);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and in you activity `onCreate()`, call `AsyncTask` as,

```
new MyTask().execute();
```